# Create API in WSO2 API Manager from WSO2 AS

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a service exposed in my AS at the url: http://192.168.7.160:8284/customer/XXX where XXX is the customer id like http://192.168.7.160:8284/customer/1020

I'm having some difficult to create an API in Api Manager to consume this service.

I try to set the URL Pattern to /customer with a parameter named customer with no luck.

How can I consume this AS service in the Api Manager?

Comment: What shold be your API URL? I hope  `http://192.168.7.160:8284/customer` must be your backend service.

Comment: Yes. But how to pass a parameter to it?
In the Api Manager, if I set the parameter the url called is https://192.168.7.160:8249/customer/1.0.0?customer=1010 and not https://192.168.7.160:8249/customer/1.0.0/1010

If I not set a parameter the url called is https://192.168.7.160:8249/customer/1.0.0

Comment: You can enabled default version of API, then you don't need to include version. And when you creating API. you can have a path parameter link {id} in resource, then you can have http://192.168.7.160:8284/customer/1020

Comment: Following your tip now it's working. tank you.